# Updating a matrix row in an existing entry using a frontend form

Tags: matrix, frontend-form

I am trying to update a specific row in a matrix field using a frontend form, I created them using another form with each row following the [new1], [new2] etc. naming format, but I can't seem to get it working using the code below

```
{% for block in entry.fieldOrderItemsMatrix.all() %}
    <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      {{ csrfInput() }}
      {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
      {{ hiddenInput('sectionId', craft.app.sections.getSectionByHandle('orders').id) }}
      {{ hiddenInput('entryId', entry.id) }}
      <input type="checkbox" name="fields[fieldOrderItemsMatrix][new{{ loop.index }}][fields][fieldOrderDelivered]" {{ delivered ? 'checked' }}>
      <span>Delivered</span>
      <button>Save</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use `new1`, `new2` etc for creating **new** matrix blocks during the submission. For editing existing blocks, you need to use the block's ID in that same place. In your case that would be `block.id`.